# How to conditionally expose or hide properties of nested objects in API Platform with Symfony6?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

I am developing an API using Symfony 6 and API Platform, and have run into a situation where I need to conditionally expose or hide certain properties of nested objects based on the role of the authenticated user.

I have a User class with properties like **id**, **email**, **name**, and a collection of **followers**. Each follower is also an instance of the User class. I want to control the visibility of these properties based on the role of the user who is making the request.

```
#[Groups(['get'])]
private $id;

#[Groups(['get-owner'])]
private $email;

#[Groups(['get'])]
private $name;

#[MongoDB\ReferenceMany(storeAs: "id", targetDocument: self::class, inversedBy: "followers")]
#[Groups(['get-owner'])]
private Collection $followers;
```

The **email** property is annotated with a **get-owner** group, which means it should be visible only to the owner of the object. This works fine for the top-level User object. However, when I get a list of followers (which are also User objects), I can see their emails as well because they are included in the get-owner group.

My problem is: even though I am the owner of the top-level User object, I am not the owner of the follower User objects, so I should not be able to see their emails. But because the get-owner group applies to all User objects, not just the top-level one, I am seeing more information than I should.

So, how can I set a specific serialization group for the data inside followers? Or, how can I handle this kind of scenario where I need to expose/hide certain properties conditionally based on some factors like ownership?

I'm looking for a way to resolve this issue that adheres to the architecture and principles of Symfony and API Platform.

Any insights, suggestions, or best practices on how to deal with this type of situation would be greatly appreciated.